# custom gallery from user phone

Tags: nativescript

I want to be able to show the user images from his phone gallery, and pick one or more, the images should be displayed in 2 or more columns according to the user choice. 
I looked for some plugins, and didn't find one that solves that problem.
Is that possible using conventional Android/iOS functionality?

If not, I could build a custom gallery for the user, but the question is- how do I get all the gallery names (Video/Camera/Screenshots) etc.) and file paths?

Tried to look in [nativescript-imagepicker](https://github.com/simplec-dev/nativescript-imagepicker), but it doesn't seem to give me that functionality. Any help would be appriciated

Comment: [nativescript-imagepicker](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker) do show the gallery, images in columns and allows you pick one or more images. That exactly you need is missing in that plugin?

Comment: It's a great plugin and I have used it in previous apps. This time I need to be able to change the number of columns in the push of a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to customise the layout then you got to build one from scratch. You would have to use the native apis, [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) on Android / [PhotoKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit?language=objc) on iOS to read available image list and wrap them on your own layout.